# Couchbase server timeout expired after upgrade to 3.1.0

Tags: couchbase

We recently upgraded our cluster from Couchbase 2.5.1 to 3.1.0. 
But when trying to update documents or read from an index, we're getting 'timeout expired' errors. That happens from .NET client and curl/postman. We use .NET client 2.1.2 if that helps.

When I looked into the logs, I found errors for document updates in couchdb.log looking like this: `couch_log:error:44]dcp client (bucket_name, mapreduce_view: bucket_name _design/main (prod/main)): Obtaining mutation from server timed out after 60.0 seconds [RequestId 318, PartId 825, StartSeq 0, EndSeq 34450]. Waiting...` 
Something is wrong with compacting/updating indexes: `Set view bucket_name, main (prod) group _design/main, compactor process <0.27790.45> died with unexpected reason: {updater_died,                                                                                                                          {updater_error,                                                                                                                           {view_group_index_updater_exit,                                                                                                                            96,                                                                                                                            <<>>}}}` 
What does it mean?

Comment: does it work on the UI?

Comment: I didn't try, let me do so

Comment: yes it works in the UI

Comment: Then I guess the problem is with the client.

Can't really help you - not usin the .net client. Perhaps you can ask for help on their github page (but i'd look for logs, first).

Comment: UPD added log information

Comment: I ran a quick google search: this might be a CB bug after-all: it might be failing to calculate views.

1. Do you have views defined? perhaps you can delete and redefine them?
2. for reference: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-11889?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

Comment: I saw that issue too, but it's marked as fixed in 3.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90869/discussion-between-fuzzyami-and-chester89).

Answer (score 0):

We ended up dropping views data and recreating views from scratch